# Проверить на содержание списка в списке

Tags: java, list, arraylist

Как проверить содержится ли один список в другом, сравнивая объекты по значениям, а не по ссылке.

```
    List<Data> nl = new ArrayList<>();
    nl.add(new Data("1"));
    nl.add(new News("2"));
    nl.add(new News("3"));

    List<News> nl2 = new ArrayList<>();
    nl2.add(new News("1"));
    nl2.add(new News("2"));

    System.out.print(nl.containsAll(nl2)); // false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Методы типа `contains` работают через вызов метода `equals` (и `hashCode()`) сравниваемых объектов.

Т.е. вам надо переопределить этот метод в вашем классе Data так, чтобы он возвращал нужное значение в зависимости от нужной вам логики. Вообще в современных `IDE` это можно сделать в пару кликов. Вот пример такого переопределения для простого класса:

```
public class Item {
    public String sku;

    public Item(String sku) {
        this.sku = sku;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        Item item = (Item) o;

        return sku.equals(item.sku);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return sku.hashCode();
    }
}
```

В этом классе, в методе equals идут проверки на

1. Равенство ссылок.
2. На то что один из сравниваемых объектов не `null`
3. Классы сравниваемых объектов совпадают
4. Значение переменных `sku` у обоих совпадают

Если вы добавите подобный код в ваш класс то методы типа `contains` будут выдавать вам `true` в т.ч. при равенстве заданных параметров